# Resolve is not defined when loading script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a function to load a number of scripts in  JavaScript. The scripts load without a problem, but the console will throw "Uncaught ReferenceError: resolve is not defined" at the line `.done(resolve('All scripts were loaded'))` when running loadModules().

I have just started to learn async functions and am at a loss here so I would appreciate some help.

My code is

```
/*Loads several scripts*/
function loadModules() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    jQuery.loadScript("js/script1.js");
    jQuery.loadScript("js/script2.js");

  })
    .done(resolve('All scripts were loaded'))
    .fail(reject);
}

/*Loads a single script*/
jQuery.loadScript = function (url) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        async: true
    })
    .done(resolve('Script loaded'))
    .fail(reject);
  })
}
```

Comment: Try adding a function to the done event: `.done(_ => resolve('Script loaded'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resolve` and `reject` are only going to be available inside the closure. You're trying to use them outside of it. You could do something like

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Promise.all([
    // load scripts
  ])
  .then(resolve)
  .catch(reject);
})
```

Comment: Tip: `Promise.all` already returns a Promise. Don't wrap it with a `new Promise`. Just `return Promise.all([ ... ]);`